# How to retrieve a trained model docker image deployed to ACI?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I've trained a model and deployed it to ACI using Azure ML studio. It works as expected. Now I want to download the docker image and use it in my local environment. Is it possible to download the image using CLI?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: Nope. ACR is empty, I see the container in ACI only. And it's impossible to download it.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the ACI image message?

Answer (score 0):

Azure ML Studio must have pushed a container image somewhere before spinning up a container instance on ACI. You might be able to find out the image name by using Docker's [ACI integration](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/aci-integration/). For instance, you could run...

```
$ docker login azure

$ docker context create aci myacicontext

$ docker ps
```

... and check the `IMAGE` value of your running container, and see if you can pull that image to your local machine. If not, you might be able to create a new one using [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Export, copy and commit commands are not available in the ACI context

Comment: What's the image name? Where did it push the image?

Comment: I pushed the image to ACI using AML studio deploy button. The image name is autogenerated

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to push an image directly to ACI. It would first get pushed to a registry such as Docker Hub or ACR, and then ACI would pull it from there. So the question is, can you pull the image from that same registry from your local machine. I'm not familiar with Azure ML Studio, but would suggest researching more in this direction.

Comment: Yes, I'm available to download from Azure Container registry but there is no image with the model. I can see only in aci context https://imgur.com/t4au3gv

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to download the docker image and use it in my local
> environment. Is it possible to download the image using CLI?

It's possible to download the Docker image via CLI. When you trained a model and deployed it to ACI using Azure ML studio, there must be a place to store the images. Private registry or the public registry. You can see the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-custom-image), you can use a private registry such as the ACR, or other private registries. You can also use the  Azure Machine Learning base images stored in the Microsoft registry, it's similar to the Docker hub.

If you have known where is the docker images stored, then you can download the docker images to your local environment.

From the public registry such as the Docker hub, you can pull the images directly:

```
docker pull image:tag
```

If it's a private registry, you need to log in with the credential first, for example, you use the Azure Container Registry:

```
docker login myacr.azurecr.io -u username -p password
docker pull myacr.azurecr.io/image:tag
```

Of course, you need to install the Docker server in your local environment first.

Comment: That is the point. I have no idea there is the image stored. I can't select the registry to store the image https://imgur.com/a/armKqEH and all my registries are empty. Also, I can't do anything with the ACI images https://imgur.com/a/upo5nVn

Comment: @Artem When you integrate ACI with the docker compose, then you cannot change the image locally. And as the second screenshot shows, the first image is stored in the ACR and the second image is a public image stored in the Microsoft registry. If you want to make changes to the images, you need to download them to local and do the changes. So I don't know why you cannot know where are the images stored.

Comment: I don't use docker compose. I just deploy the model from ML Studio. I don't want to change the images, I want to download them and use locally. And I said previously, my registry on Azure portal is empty.

Comment: @Artem When you deploy the images to the ACI, you can get the image information from the ACI, then you can download the images. So I don't know why you cannot find where do the images store.